# Create Map Pins from XML/Array

Tags: ios, xml, swift, mapkit

I'm currently working on a project which grabs a bunch of traffic-cameras from a XML file and and shows them in the app. I have got my Tableview up and running, working perfectly (click on a cell, opens detailView and shows traffic-image). However, I want to display the cameralocations on a map, so users can press the pin they want to see the camera of (and it sends them to a detailView to show the camera).

I'm not sure how to make this work, any ideas?

I got the longitude and latitude coordinates. Link to the XML file: http://webkamera.vegvesen.no/metadata

It is in norwegian but, lengdegrad = longitude and breddegrad = latitude.

This is what I want to achieve (Photoshop screenshot): https://gyazo.com/93d885606efd6e6369018243b64d47e8

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but please help if you know something :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To use the XML data:**

Add the XML file to your project and use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLParser/parse) to read it.

**To create annotations on the map:**

Create an annotation class based on [MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/index.html), something like that:

```
class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    // optionally add subtitle

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title

    } 
}
```

To create and add the anotations to the map, for each of the parsed items from your XML file create one annotation and add it to the map. Something like this, depending on format of your parsed data. Let's say you have the data in an array called cameras:

```
for camera in cameras {
    let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(camera.latitude, camera.longitude)
    let annotation = Annotation(coordinate: coord, title: camera.title)                      
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: Creating each pin manually? Adding url, coordinates, roadname etc. manually will take a lot of time, because it's about 350 cameras. However, if it's the only solution, I better start soon :P :) Thanks for the answer, btw

Comment: I understand that you were able to use the xml data in your table already. If you already have it in a form that can be iterated through, you can create the annotations in a loop.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Have no idea on how to do it, but going to search around and read up on the MKAnnotationView link you posted earlier.

Comment: I thought you already have the XML data parsed. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I have the XML Parsed out (currently used by the tableView). What I can't figure out, is how to use this information to create one annotation for each camera/object and place them on the map. Can .zip you the project tomorrow and you'll see what I mean (if you want to take a look of course). I have never used the MapKit before, so I'm kind of stuck here.. English is not my native language, so I might have expressed me wrong earlier, sorry about that :)

Comment: See if my latest addition shed more light on the problem. You just create the annotation object(s) with coordinates and title and call addAnnotation method of your map outlet.